# App uses to much memory as time increases

Tags: android, react-native, sqlite, ram

My app takes too much memory; 1GB and increases by time. If my app stays open for two days it crashes. Two possible causes:

1. `utils-decorators` used to cache data from an API:

```js
import { memoizeAsync, Cache, memoize } from 'utils-decorators';

  @memoizeAsync({
    expirationTimeMs: 1000 * 60 * 60,
    cache: serviceTempData.HttpClientCache
  })
  async getHtml(url: string, isImage?: boolean): Promise<HTMLElement>{
      ....  
  }
```

The custom cache :

```js
export default class CustomCache implements Cache<any> {
    private loadedFiles = new Map<string, any>();
    private maxItems: number;
    private clearSize: number;
    constructor(maxItems?: number, clearSize?: number) {
        this.maxItems = maxItems ?? 1000;
        this.clearSize = clearSize ?? 500;
    }

    keys(){
        var result = [] as string[];
        for(var x of this.loadedFiles.keys())
            result.push(x);
        return result;
    }

    clearAll() {
        this.loadedFiles.clear();
    }

    validate() {
        var counter = this.clearSize;
        if (this.loadedFiles.size > this.maxItems)
            for (var key of this.loadedFiles.keys()) {
                counter--;
                this.loadedFiles.delete(key);
                if (counter <= 0)
                    break;
            }
    }

    set = (key: string, parameter: any) => {
        this.validate();
        this.loadedFiles.set(key, parameter);
    }
    get = (key: string) => {
        return this.loadedFiles.get(key);
    }
    delete = (key: string) => {
        if (this.loadedFiles.has(key))
            this.loadedFiles.delete(key)
    }
    has = (key: string) => {
        return this.loadedFiles.has(key)
    }
}
```

2. Using `expo.sqlight`. I build and ORM [expo-sqlite-wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-sqlite-wrapper) around `expo-sqlight`.

I also have a background service running:

```js
    while (BackgroundService.isRunning()) {
            const dData = [...downloads.filter(x => serviceOperations.DownloadTasks[x.novel] === undefined)]
            if (dData.length > 0) {
                await dData.asyncForeach(async x => {
                    console.log("Downloading" + x.novel);
                    serviceOperations.DownloadTasks[x.novel] = x;
                    var parser = BackGroundOperator.includedParser.find(f => x.parserName == f.name);
                    if (parser) {
                        var novel = await parser.getNovel(x.novel)
                        parser.downloadNovel(novel, () => {
                            if (BackGroundOperator.onDownloadStart && BackGroundOperator.onDownloadStart[x.novel] != undefined) {
                                BackGroundOperator.onDownloadStart[x.novel]();
                                delete BackGroundOperator.onDownloadStart[x.novel];
                            }

                        });
                    }
                });
            }

            if (!workingOnMessages)
                validateMessages();

            if (!BackGroundOperator.serviceData && data) {
                console.log("Playing")
                BackGroundOperator.serviceData = data;
                AudioService.task(BackGroundOperator.includedParser);
            } else if (!data)
                BackGroundOperator.serviceData = undefined;


            if (!isWorking)
                checkRemovableFiles();

            if (!workingOnSessionProgress)
                validateSession();

            if (__DEV__ && pinger % 100 === 0) {
                console.log("Service is still alive")
                pinger = 0;
            }

            await HttpClient.wait(4000);
            if (__DEV__)
                pinger++
        }
```

Comment: Try taking out one dependency at a time and use the profiling tools in Xcode/ Android Studio to see what is adding to your memory usage. It may not be a dependency, it can be something in your code, like keeping a tab mounted and loading the same images again, etc. The best way to find it is to experiment

Comment: Yah i did that and used devtools and found the issue. read above if you are intressted